# How do I do a batch downgrade of packages from one repo back to canonical?

Tags: apt, package-management

Ubuntu 15.10 x86_64
While trying to do an install of Bumblebee, I followed instructions to add the xorg-edgers PPA. A more recent tutorial advised against it. However, by then,it was already too late: several packages were already updated to the xorg-edgers versions.

I thought I might be able to go into Synaptic and force-version these packages back to Canonical. This worked for some packages, but it quickly turned into a dependency nightmare. Some downgrades wanted to uninstall other packages, and some (libegl1-mesa-dev), if elected to be downgraded rather than removed, threatened to uninstall nearly every package currently installed, including everything xorg.

Is there an easy way to roll back everything from a PPA back to Canonical?

**In response to "possible duplicate", removing the PPA wasn't the problem, but rather rolling back the packages without causing a firestorm of dependency problems proved most challenging. However,in the suggested answer, the solution to my question was also given; namely, the ppa-purge solution.

Comment: E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
E: Unable to lock the download directory

Comment: Now I'm getting message like this from Synaptic

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can PPAs be removed?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is an easy way.

Just install [ppa-purge](https://launchpad.net/ppa-purge)

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
```

Then you should run it against the PPA you added, in this case:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

It should disable the PPA and rollback any package updated from the PPA back to the ones in the Ubuntu official repository.

http://www.webupd8.org/2012/02/how-to-use-launchpad-ppa-add-remove.html